# После компелляции кода Python, не учитывется оператор if

Tags: python, if

После того, как я вложил строчную информацию в переменную password, должно было высветиться "нет", но лишь высветилась следующая функция.

[image]

Comment: И правда. Питон также и к пробелам после компелляции, как оказывается, чувствителен. Спасибо! –nomnoms12

Comment: Простите, но Python интерпретируемый. А если Вы желаете вводить пробел, то можете использовать функцию `strip`, когда проверяете пароль. Она удаляет пробельные символы в начале и в конце строки. Подробнее о ней можете прочитать [тут](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=strip#string.strip).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вводите пароль с пробелом. На скриншоте, благодаря моноширинному шрифту, это отчётливо видно.

Если вводить без него, то всё отлично работает:

[image: Правильный вариант]

Исходный код (Python 3.x.x):

```py
print("начало программы")
password = input("Введи пароль:")

if password == '1234':
    print("нет")

print("конец программы")
```